# `ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names` instruction meaning

Tags: python, posix

I am new to python and I would like to know what this instruction is for:

`ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names`

I know it might seem trivial to most of you but I could not find a clear explanation on the internet.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names` returns a boolean value, which is stored in variable `ON_POSIX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a high-level perspective you're checking if `posix` module is built-in the Python Interpreter ( meaning compiled into the Python interpreter itself).

`sys.builtin_module_names` returns a tuple of strings giving the names of all modules that are compiled into this Python interpreter.

If you take a look at the posix module :

```py
import posix
help(posix)
```

You can see that this module is built-in :

```
Help on built-in module posix:

NAME
    posix

FILE
    (built-in)

MODULE DOCS
    http://docs.python.org/library/posix

DESCRIPTION
    This module provides access to operating system functionality that is
    standardized by the C Standard and the POSIX standard (a thinly
    disguised Unix interface).  Refer to the library manual and
    corresponding Unix manual entries for more information on calls.
```

By contrast you can do the same for `os` module:

```py
import os
help(os)
```

As you can see os in not compiled into the Python Interpreter `FILE: /usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py`:

```
Help on module os:

NAME
    os - OS routines for Mac, NT, or Posix depending on what system we're on.

FILE
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py
```